# How do I assign blank space to the separator in MapReduce program while having key as null and setNumReduceTasks(0)

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I have tried `conf.set("mapreduce.output.textoutputformat.separator","");` but it didnt work.

**O/P am getting**

```
{tab space}val1

{tab space}val2
```

**O/P Expected**

```
val1

val2
```

Comment: Dear varun, for having a better feedback on your question, please, include sourcecodes ,scenario .

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out :). I didn't need the Mapper key in the output. So, I kept it as nullWritable and passed null in the output, which in turn got only the mapper output value without any spaces